# Batch hostednetwork IF ELSE not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command

I would like to write a batch script, but i'm not very good at it.
I want to start my hostednetwork if it isn't running. If it is already running, I want to stop it. Could somebody help me please?
This is what I have:

```
@echo off
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
if not (hostednetwork==started) goto start
else goto stop 

:start
    netsh wlan start hostednetwork
    goto end

:stop
```

Comment: `if not "hostednetwork"=="started" goto start` if you compare two different constants, this will never be true  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string "hostednetwork" will never be the same as the string "started"

Also, you have a syntax error with your `else`statement. Nevertheless, you don't need it:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork|find "Status"|find "started">nul && goto stop || goto start
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I only had to switch STOP and START.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who would like to use this method, here is the complete working code

```
@ECHO OFF
netsh wlan show hostednetwork|find "Status"|find "Started">nul && goto stop || goto start
:start
    netsh wlan start hostednetwork
    goto end

:stop
    netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
    goto end

:end 
    PAUSE
```

Thanks to those who put into the creation of this method